# CORS error with Angular UI and Node backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, cors

I'm new to node and need some help.

I'm getting: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:`

my angular app is launching from `http://localhost:4200`

And I'm making an api request (which works on postman) to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin`

but I'm getting CORS errors.

In my node server.js, I have the following configured:

```js
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
      next();
    });
```

And I can post data using postman to: `localhost:3000/api/auth/signin`

Comment: How do you make the API request from your angular app?

Comment: Make sure that your router should be register after your server configuration.

Comment: `http://localhost:3000` needs to set CORS headers not `http://localhost:4200`.

Answer (score -1):

It's because Browser will send something called *preflight* request, and Postman will not. So, your server has to respond to these preflight requests first, in order for Browser to proceed with original request.

Your code will just call `next()` which will proceed to the next middleware, but what will that middleware do after? You should send `200` on `OPTIONS` request immediately.

---

Alternatively, you can quickly add cors logic with [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

...

app.use(cors());
```